# VBA question: Cannot get html element after clicked to another page

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I wish to make a macro which can auto login a page and then autofill the search input field and finally web scraping the search result.

I have been struggling for a long time that I can successfully login the page. However, when I click the login button, I cannot further get the input tag for the search field as well as adding the value to that input field. The index of those input tags are absolutely correct.

Below is my vba script, many thanks!

```
Sub login_and_search()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://loginpage.html"

    Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set inputElement = .document.getELementsByTagName("input")
    inputElement.Item(0).Value = "abc" 'username
    inputElement.Item(1).Value = "xyz" 'password
    inputElement.Item(2).Click

    Do While ie.Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set searchField = .document.getELementsByTagName("input")
    searchField.Item(0).Value = "searchitems" 'search field
    searchField.Item(1).Click

End With

End Sub
```

Below are the 2 html files, sorry for the too simplified html files as I roughly make them for testing the vba script only. The first one is the login page and the second one is the page after login.

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="" action="search.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <input type="password" name="" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="login">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="" action="searchResults.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Search">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no error showing when running the macro, I think it is a logic error instead of syntax error.

Once again, thanks all!

Comment: please can you share the html after the login page. Use the snippet tool via [edit]. Not as an image. Do you get any error message? Can you also use syntax  searchField(0).Value ="" etc

Comment: I have added login page as well as the html after the login. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What do you observe happening when submit it hit - are values retained?

Comment: No error message is obtained. However, I figured out that after I go to the page after login,  I still get the same length of input tag in login page. That means the “searchField” variable is not getting the elements in the search page but in the login page.

Comment: you can print the html to check

Comment: Finally found a tricks to solve this problem , I added application.wait for 1 second before auto filling the search field. But I did have a line of code for the page to load completely, anyone knows the reason?

Comment: there may still be things running after URL navigated to e.g. js on page, there can be anti-bot measures re timings.... I usually use a loop..for example, in this case if the search field is selectable but empty intially I would use a timed loop entering info into that field until it wasn't empty.